How to reduce React Native App size using these simple methods
I have used

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
release {
debuggable false
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true
setProguardFiles([getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'])
}
Also reduce image size

Resolve my issue "How to reduce React Native App size using these simple methods"
